# Rails 4: HABTM Checkbox issue -- nil error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I have a HABTM relationship between learning objectives and tasks. I was able to implement checkboxes via http://railscasts.com/episodes/17-habtm-checkboxes. However, I am running into an issue when all the boxes are unchecked. See blow

form:

```
<% for task in Task.all %>
<%= check_box_tag "tlo[task_ids][], task.id, @tlo.tasks.include?(task) %>
<%= task.name%>
<%end%>
```

TLO controller:

```
    def update
     params[:tlo][task_ids] ||= []
     respond_to do |format|
       if(@tlo.update)
        format.html {redirect_to @tlo}
       end
      end
   end
```

Yes, `task_ids: []` in my permitted params. When looking in the log its says `undefined method [] for nil:nilClass.` Some resources say because on a form with only checkboxes with none selected won't submit anything? Does anyone have suggestions for a workaround?

Comment: It appears (from the error) that `params[:tlo]` is nil. Could you show us the entire form? What's the value of `params`? You are missing a " in the form code, I'm sure that's just here in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a checkbox is unchecked, its parameter is omitted from being sent with the submitted form. If all checkboxes of a given name are uncheked, the relevant parameter is not included with the request. This is the reason you're getting `nil` when trying to access it.

To keep the parameter with the request you need a hidden field with an empty value. Place it before all the checkboxes in your form.

```
<%= hidden_field_tag "tlo[task_ids][]", '' %>
```

Comment: OMG! You are genius! I've spent 2 days on this problem!